# Plot.ly pie chart result precision

Tags: python, charts, plotly, pie-chart

How do I set precision to 1 decimal point when generating simple pie charts using plot.ly python lib?

Here's a sample code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

question = {
    'A': 3,
    'B': 7,
    'C': 6,
    'D': 11,
    'E': 6
}

trace = go.Pie(labels=list(question.keys()), values=list(question.values()))
py.image.save_as([trace], filename='output.png')
```

That creates the following chart:

[image: sample pie chart]

As you can see on the image, value for "A" is computed as 9.09%, thus if we sum up all the chart percentage we're left with 99,99%.

Is there a param for the plot.ly api to make them round up the "A" value to 9.1%, so that each chart percentage value would use 1 decimal point precision (and sum to 100%)?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A',3],['B',7], ['C',6], ['D',11], ['E',6]], columns=['letter','value'])

fig = px.pie(df,  names='letter', values='value')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{percent:.1%f}')
fig.show()
```

This produces:

[image: pie_chart]

Comment: Cool, but how do you make this work together with `textinfo='percent+label'` ?

Comment: @CarloBianchi `texttemplate` can override `textinfo`. This might produce the result you want: `fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{percent:.1%f} %{label}')`

Comment: In plotly 5.3.1, this should be '%{percent:.1%}' without the "f"